# What does it mean, "luxury of worrying"?

Tags: meaning

Dick Best speaks to pilot, who wants to withdraw from the war, about his father:

> Dick Best: You know how I got his respect? By always staying in the
>   fight. I wish I had the **luxury of worrying** about your confidence, but
>   we're short on pilots, so, you gotta suck it up.

What does it mean, "luxury of worrying"?

I never saw "luxury" used as collective noun.

I find this line in movie Midway 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "luxury" is "a pleasure obtained only rarely".  The characters are using "luxury" rather ironically here.

A wartime pilot is very busy and lives a very dangerous life. They could be killed almost any time.  A wartime pilot does not have time to worry about "do I have the confidence of my peers".  From the point of view of a wartime pilot, having enough free time to worry about "confidence" would be better than always working in a job and being at risk of death. So, ironically, "worrying" is a luxury.

Comment: +1, but I had to read it twice to understand the second sentence; make it clearer as to whether you’re talking about the scriptwriters or the characters.

Comment: Really? Second paragraph or second sentence? I though by saying "A wartime pilot..." three times would make it clear enough that I'm describing the point of view of the characters.  Being killed is not a hazard most scriptwriters face!

Answer (score 0):

**luxury** is not a collective noun. In this context, a luxury is something that you would like, but cannot afford. You use this expression when you are not able to do something. If, for example, you have a backlog of work and a colleague invites you to join her for lunch, you would say:

> I wish I had the luxury of being able to take a lunch break.

You don't have time to take a lunch break, so taking a lunch break seems like a luxury.